# How to create a financial evaluation model using python?

Tags: python, excel, user-interface, finance

I a ma a python newbie and learning the basics. But I am pretty good with Excel and even created investment analysis models which are quite flexible to the requirements, using the inbuilt functions of ms excel.

I feel python syntax is pretty easy to pick up in comparison to the excel VBA. But my problem is how to create investment models using the python which just generates the output in a plain window.

Is there any user interface such as visual basic of Microsoft, in Python which is quite easy to create evaluation models?

Comment: I can vaguely imagine what you mean by "evaluation models" but not concretely. Can you link or demonstrate some example of what you want? Mostly stack overflow is for more specific questions but I guess you will get a few general answers.

Comment: I have created a investment evaluation model in excel for renewable energy projects. The following are the key inputs, capacity (MW), Project cost, Construction period and operation expenses and debt repayment. The excel model would generate a cashflow for the plant operational period (20 years). Based on the cashflow the NPV, IRR and forecast income statement & Balance Sheet can be produced. The most important thing is that the cashflow would be for years ( each 12 months).However the model would shift the cashflow even if the construction period is in 15 months.

Comment: I mostly used if, and conditions in excel to create the model. But with python I feel i can directly create it with loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already good with excel, why not just [automate it with python](http://www.python-excel.org/) instead of VBA? What does excel not do that you need to do?